# how to get the max size used by a field in table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a field which has been set to max size. How can i find the max size occupied by the field.

For example if the records are for table TableA

```
FieldA

123
abcd
1234567
```

I need to know which row occupied the most size and what the size is, how?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[LEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx) tests for the length in characters, e.g. "a" = 1 char

```
select max(len(fieldA)) from tbl
```

[DATALENGTH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx) checks for the size in bytes, an NVarchar occupies 2 bytes per character

```
select max(datalength(fieldA)) from tbl
```

To get all the rows in the table that have the maximum length of data in FieldA,

```
select *
from tbl join (select MAX(LEN(fieldA)) maxlen from tbl) l
    on l.maxlen = LEN(tbl.fieldA)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES * 
FROM tbl
ORDER BY len(tbl.fieldA) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You may to query this sql

```
Select Character_Maximum_Length
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
Where TABLE_CATALOG Like 'DatabaseName' And TABLE_NAME Like 'TableName' And COLUMN_NAME Like 'FieldName'
```