# How to get maximum size used by a string in Hive?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I want to know the maximum length a particular string column is taking.
I tried taking the approached mentioned here :
[how to get the max size used by a field in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711518/how-to-get-the-max-size-used-by-a-field-in-table) but did not work in Hive
but that did not work in Hive.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In that example they use `len`, use `length` instead:

```
select max(length(mycolumn)) from mytable;
```

This works fine in hive QL.

Answer (score -1):

multiple ways to check length of column in where clause as well:

`select max(length(column_name)),min(length(column_name)) from table_name where length(column_name)<15`

Here, checked column length with max and min values. Also use where clause if checking column length lesser than 15